# Can we use pact-jvm for validation soap xml?

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

I have tried using pact-JVM for an endpoint which returns a soap XML response.

For XML response it looks like it does string comparison, Can we do XML validation against XSD or can we write matchers for XML?

Need suggestion as well, is it a good idea to use pact-JVM to write a contract test case for an endpoint that returns soap XML?

Please share a sample example for it.

Answer (score 0):

There is a PactXMLBuilder that you can use that is namespace aware and you can match on.

Here is an example https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/blob/7ff6491a0923e4709a8f78ab5451a99989559712/consumer/junit/src/test/java/au/com/dius/pact/consumer/junit/xml/TodoXmlTest.java